# How to write to a csv file with no newline using powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I want each row to be populated with the data retrieved from each file. Currently, the 2nd and 3rd column entries are being written to a newline.[CSV file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2plT.png) I have tried using "export-csv" and the "-nonewline" command. Perhaps there is a regex command that would solve this?

```
#Column headings
$headings = "Source file, Review file existence, Review Result, Compilation Check Result, Static Analysis Result, Review up-to-date, Reviewed code version, Latest code version"
# Create array with $headings as first input
$output = @($headings)


$SourceParentDir = "C:\Document"
$Files = get-childitem -Path $SourceParentDir -Recurse -Filter '*.?pp' | % { $_.FullName }
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $BaseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($File)
# Populate each row for each file
    $output += $BaseName
    $output += ", Review Exists" # writes to a newline
    $output += ", " + $Result + "," + $Compilation + "," + $StaticAnalysis + "," + $UpToDateFlag + "," + $ReviewFileVersionNumber + "," + $SourceFileVersionNumber + ","
}

# write output to a csv file
$output | Out-File -FilePath Documents\Example-csv.csv -encoding utf8
```

Comment: You declare `$output` as an array. So each item will be on a separate line.

Comment: Can you include examples of expected output and actual output in your question? It will be much easier to understand what you want.

Comment: What a weird way to create a csv file. You keep repeating variables like `$Result`, `$Compilation` etc that seem to come from nowhere for every file in the `$Files` array. Also, **ALL** of your headers except the first one will have space characters in front. Is that really what you want? Please explain the question further so we know what your intention and desired output file is.

Comment: A quick fix would be to do: `$headings = "Source file,Review file existence,Review Result,Compilation Check Result,Static Analysis Result,Review up-to-date,Reviewed code version,Latest code version"` and later inside the loop: `$output += $BaseName,"Review Exists",$Result,$Compilation,$StaticAnalysis,$UpToDateFlag,$ReviewFileVersionNumber,$SourceFileVersionNumber -join ","`. Pesonally, I would use a  `[PsCustomObject]` script like the one @BaconBits shwos you in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do things that way, but there's definitely a more-Powershelley way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceParentDir -Recurse -Filter '*.?pp' |
ForEach-Object {
    $File = $_

    # Put your other code here

    # This will output an object to the stream
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Source file' = $File.Name
        'Review file existence' = 'Review Exists'
        'Review Result' = $Result
        'Compilation Check Result' = $Compilation
        'Static Analysis Result' =  $StaticAnalysis
        'Review up-to-date' = $UpToDateFlag
        'Reviewed code version' = $ReviewFileVersionNumber
        'Latest code version' = $SourceFileVersionNumber
    }   
} | Export-Csv Example-csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The big drawback here is that you don't get a lot of formatting choices about the CSV. Every field is quoted, for example.

---

Alternately, if you really want really detailed control of the `$output` string, you should use a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) instead of a `String`. `StringBuilder` is one of the most potent and widely used classes in C#. This is because strings in C# and Powershell are immutable, so when you `+=` a String you create a new string, copy everything over with the new bit, then throw the old string away. It can be very memory intensive with large operations. StringBuilder lets you get around all that. It's a class that's designed to let you append stuff to strings and format them however you want.

You instance it like so:

```
$output = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
```

And then you typically call one of two methods to add text. `Append($string)` appends the string, `AppendLine($string)` appends the line and then adds a newline. You can also call `AppendLine()` with no argument to just add a newline. To get your final string, you call the `ToString()` method. The append methods do return a status when you call them which you can prevent from outputting pretty easily with a `[void]`, or by saving it to another variable if you need it.

```
$output = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
[void]$output.AppendLine($headings)


$SourceParentDir = "C:\StarTeam\00011114-JSENS_TRS\ATR\04_SW_Implementation\Operational"
$Files = get-childitem -Path $SourceParentDir -Recurse -Filter '*.?pp' | % { $_.FullName }
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $BaseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($File)
# Populate each row for each file
    [void]$output.Append($BaseName)
    [void]$output.Append(", Review Exists")
    [void]$output.Append(", $Result,$Compilation,$StaticAnalysis,$UpToDateFlag,$ReviewFileVersionNumber,$SourceFileVersionNumber,")
    [void]$output.AppendLine()
}

$output.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath Documents\Example-csv.csv -encoding utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

`$output` is an array, so each of those `+=` inside the loop is a new entry in the array, and therefore a new line in the file.

You can fix this by using a temporary string variable in the middle of the loop, and appending it to `$output` once at the end of each iteration:

```
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $row = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($File)
    $row += ", Review Exists" 
    $row += ", " + $Result + "," + $Compilation + "," + $StaticAnalysis + "," + $UpToDateFlag + "," + $ReviewFileVersionNumber + "," + $SourceFileVersionNumber + ","
  
    $output += $row
}
```

or by putting everything in one big string interpolation:

```
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $BaseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($File)
    $output += "$BaseName, Review Exists, $Result, $Compilation, $StaticAnalysis, $UpToDateFlag, $ReviewFileVersionNumber, $SourceFileVersionNumber"
}
```

But I agree with the other answer that building up an array of custom objects for the `Export-Csv` commandlet is more idiomatic for PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you're populating $Output. Since it is defined as an array, each time you're adding new information it's creating a new entry rather than just adding the additional information to a string.

If you make your $output into one line with all required fields it should correct it without you changing the array.

```
$output += $BaseName + ", Review Exists" + ", " + $Result + "," + $Compilation + "," + $StaticAnalysis + "," + $UpToDateFlag + "," + $ReviewFileVersionNumber + "," + $SourceFileVersionNumber + ","
```

Comment: Too many cats: `$output += "$($BaseName), Review Exists, ..."`